# Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, login-control

I am using Formsauthentication for login in my small application. It works fine on my local machine but when i upload this on cloud hosting it gives error 'Your login attempt was not successful. Please try again.' message.

my login.aspx.cs file include following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ValidateUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int userId = 0;
                string roles = string.Empty;
                string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Validate_User"))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Login1.UserName);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Login1.Password);
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        reader.Read();
                        userId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserId"]);
                        roles = reader["Roles"].ToString();
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    switch (userId)
                    {
                        case -1:
                            Login1.FailureText = "Username and/or password is incorrect.";
                            break;
                        case -2:
                            Login1.FailureText = "Account has not been activated.";
                            break;
                        default:
                            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, Login1.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(2880), Login1.RememberMeSet, roles, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                            string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hash);

                            if (ticket.IsPersistent)
                            {
                                cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
                            }
                            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(Login1.UserName, Login1.RememberMeSet));
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = "Ehh.. Enter correct password..";
            }
        }
```

and my web.config file having code

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Data Source=IP Address;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;user id=Username;password=PWD;" />
    <add name="ECOLLEGEMastersEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MastersDataModel1.csdl|res://*/MastersDataModel1.ssdl|res://*/MastersDataModel1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=IP Address;initial catalog=DatabaseName;persist security info=True;user id=Username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey validationKey="24389C4FE31C25B571C6E93CBAD77C8487C66B37FF1E972D392BCC7C58A1412791CD25CA0CC8922E6F88A6B20529F26F0C3743F82E902D7C9C9BBF536B2B02C2" 
                decryptionKey="05F5BCA7FF367A1C7EC9C2E5CF898B37E445810ACB0F4E3125144321C733E93C" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <siteMap enabled="true" defaultProvider="SiteMap">
      <providers>
        <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/Web.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

and my database tables having 2 tables 
1. Roles
RoleID, RoleName
2. Users
[UserId],[Username],[Password],[Email],[CreatedDate],[LastLoginDate],[RoleId],[Status]

Please help me... I am not able to understand exact problem.

Comment: I can not understand what you do here. You have a custom login system, mixed up with asp.net authendication, and you do not know how to debug it - you do not know what you have do ? - Anyway, if work local, and not online, try to set the cookie name of cookies and authentication on web.config - see a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764260/setauthcookie-does-not-set-cookie-on-our-test-server/25769180#25769180

Comment: Its working fine on my local system. But not on cloud hosting.

Comment: I have tried domain="mydomain.com" but still not resolved...

Comment: are you sure you have live data? do you have to register?

Comment: Where does this error appear? What piece of code displays it? isolate that and work out the exact issue

Answer (score 0):

you have

```
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    etc.
}
```

but you do not have 'else...' (validate user, i suppose).